# frmvalidator validating with "onclick" because of Google recaptcha - gen_validatorv4.js

Tags: javascript, validation, recaptcha

I have a login form with Google reCaptcha invisible. This is working but I would like to validate the fields with gen_validatorv4.js. The problem is that gen_validatorv4.js works with a submit button but I would like to have it working with an onclick button/event.

Is it possible that with an onclick button/event the fields will be validated by the script gen_validatorv4.js but not submit the form as I will do that after the reCaptcha is correct?

I tried calling several functions of the gen_validatorv4.js script directly but can't get it to work.

```
var frmvalidator = new Validator("login");
function btn_click(){
    frmvalidator.addValidation('username','req','');
    frmvalidator.addValidation('password','req','');
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Proper solution is to bind click event on your button, and then submitting the form via javascript:

```
var frmvalidator = new Validator("login");

frmvalidator.addValidation('username','req','');
frmvalidator.addValidation('password','req','');

function btn_click(){
  document.login.submit()
});
```

Reference: «Triggering the validations when custom submitting the form» http://javascript-coder.com/html-form/form-validation.phtml#highlighter_522435

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However what I would like to archive is that when a button it clicked (This button triggers the recaptcha invisible) that also the form is validated. Currently I can only validate the form with the script gen_validatorv4.js when a submit is done. Is there a way to valdidate the form without a submit button

Comment: That's exactly what the code shows: when you click your button, function `btn_click` is called, so in this function, after you handled recaptcha validation, you can "simulate" form submission with `document.form.submit();`